# Minimal references to PRISM/MVVM to have the support for commands

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, prism

I am looking for information to which PRIMS/MVVM ddls I have to reference to in my project to have available Prism/MVVM functionality for handling Commands. I plan to use only this part of the frameworks.

Regards,
Wojtek

Comment: I guess what isn't clear to me is why you need to reference prism at all - SL4 has commanding built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want commanding support I would suggest to completely avoid Prism and that way you will reduce the size of your .xap file. 
I would suggest you to look at the code (either in Reflector or open Prism's source) and copy to your project all the files in "Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands" namespace in the "Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation" assembly. You can ignore CompositeCommand.

If you prefer to reference the assembly, go with "Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation". If you only use commands you won't need other assemblies. The compiler will tell you in case start using other classes from that assembly that depend on another one. The other two dependencies for this assembly (for classes other than commands) are "Microsoft.Practices.Composite" and "Microsot.Practices.ServiceLocation".